# Monitor Network Availability (for phone calls)

Tags: mobile-network, telephony

Obviously my network carrier has some problems. Though my mobile phone shows two or three bars out of four for my mobile connection, I don't receive any phone calls (not available).

Is there some kind of app or service that notifies me, if I cannot be reached by phone?

WiFi is available, so it wouldn't be sufficient to just ping an internet server. Any other ideas?

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S5 mini (SM-G800F), Android 6.0.1, Voice over LTE is not supported on that device.

Comment: You should add some more information: What Android device do you use? If it supports LTE do you have a data plan with LTE, is VoLTE active on the device and is VoLTE supported by your provider? Have you tried to enable/disable VoLTE?

Comment: Tasker automation app supports firing an action / task on the basis of signal strength. Alternatively, a time based profile can also be run which would cause the task to check signal strength and take other actions based on your set conditions. You can try it and let us know your results.

Comment: @Robert: I edited the question.

Comment: @Firelord: Does Tasker use the same signal strength that is reported in top bar in Android? If its the same, that approach would be useless, as the signal strength is always fine and also the name of my carrier is displayed on the lock screen. So that's part of my problem: It is not visible to me that I cannot be reached via phone.

Comment: @user1251007 There is only one chance: use a different phone to prove if the phone or the mobile network is the problem.